# Retrieving the last year of commit activity data

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

According to GitHub documentation, you can retrieve the last year of commit activity data PER repository by GET `/repos/:owner/:repo/stats/commit_activity`.
This can be done by:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/name/project/stats/commit_activity',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
      var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonBody, null, 2));
}

request(options, callback);
```

Another example you can retrieve the weekly commit count for the repository owner and everyone else by GET `/repos/:owner/:repo/stats/participation` but it is still done PER repository, which is not what I want.

The problem is I need the commit activity of **each week** of last year for ALL the repositories (excluding and including collaborators). How is this done?